# React Native: Force reload of TabBarIOS.item

Tags: state, react-native

I have a TabBar based app in React Native.
Multiple tabs use the same datasource (AsyncStorage).
If I'm now updating the data in one tab and open the other one, the old data is displayed.
I can't figure out, how to force a reload every time the item become active.

1. FavoritesView: display saved data
2. ExploreView: Manipulate saved data
3. FavoritesView: expired data gets displayed (--> force reload)

   ```
   <TabBarIOS.Item
   title="Explore"
   icon={{uri:'ic_explore'}}
     selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'exploreTab'}
     onPress={() => {
       this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'exploreTab'
       });
     }}>
     <ExploreView/>
   </TabBarIOS.Item>

   <TabBarIOS.Item
     title="Favorites"
     icon={{uri:'ic_favorite_border'}}
     selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'favoriteTab'}
     onPress={() => {
       this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'favoriteTab'
       });
     }}>
      // Reload this
     <FavoritesView/>
   </TabBarIOS.Item>

   <TabBarIOS.Item
     systemIcon="more"
     selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'moreTab'}
     onPress={() => {
       this.setState({
         selectedTab: 'moreTab'
       });
     }}>
     <MoreView/>
   </TabBarIOS.Item>
   ```

I already tried to set a new state to trigger an update, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
      title="Favorites"
      icon={{uri:'ic_favorite_border'}}
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'favoriteTab'}
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: 'favoriteTab',
          forceUpdate: Math.random()
        });
      }}>
      <FavoritesView forceUpdate={this.state.forceUpdate}/>
</TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Finally, I used Redux to handle my data flow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and what eventually worked for me was to override componentWillReceiveProps on the embedded views. It gets called anytime the view is set as selectedTab in the TabBarIOS.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: you should copy&paste parts of the site to your answer for better understanding and if the site will disappear

Answer (score 0):

`this` references the parent component when using fat arrow notation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

Try adding a `ref` to the TabBar item and use `this.refs.refName.forceUpdate()` (slightly nicer than updating the state with a random value as well).

Comment: I can't figure out how to implement this. Could you give me a more precise example, please? :)