# Update InitialRouteStack in React Native Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigator

I have got a Navigator that has to handle 4 different views, which should be on the same level. I am loading them in the InitialRouteStack and whenever I need one of them, I am calling jumpTo(route) and getting what I want.

However, when I change a value in one of the views, I do have a callback that updates the state of the given value where the Navigator is placed. I thought this would re-render the whole thing and update the props within the RouteStack.

This is not happening. I have also tried to run a forceUpdate() on the Navigator, but the props in each component are not updating. I keep having the values I passed when Navigator was rendered the first time.

Is there a way to solve this? I really don't want to use replace(route) because re-rendering each component every single time would be silly.

Edit
I have looked at immediatelyResetRouteStack and replacedAtIndex, but they don't seem viable. The first one reset the whole thing, the second one replaces at Index, while, in theory, I should update the props passed to each component in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015045/react-native-force-reload-of-tabbarios-item). There you can find possible solutions.

Eventually I used [`redux`](https://github.com/rackt/redux) to handle all the data flow, which solved the issue for me. There I connected every single [smart component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.a8wmnckam), at least the once included by a NavigatorIOS-Route, to the store. By that I completely bypass NavigatorIOS, together with `passProps`.

#### Known Issue

Also there exists an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/795) for react-native about rerendering a component inside NavigatorIOS, when passProps changed.

Comment: The thing is, I had the same problem with NavigatorIOS and I have solved it with componentWIllReceiveProps and events the fire the updates. However now, I am trying to write the same logic for Android, which is quite challenging.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get fired when jumpTo is called, that's the main issue. : |

Comment: And an implementation like `redux` isn't an option?
I haven't worked with react-native for android yet, sorry :/

Comment: I wanted to keep Android/iOS with a similar logic, so using redux on Android and not on iOS wouldn't be what I am looking for.

Comment: I mean using `redux` for the whole application. It is pure JS, so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just trying to find a workaround instead of refactoring the whole application. ForceUpdate() should work, but it's not doing anything. :\

Comment: purii, how did you make redux update components inside a <NavigatorIOS> update? I have a <TabBarIOS>.  I can drill down into <NavigatorIOS> details, change a redux state.  All is good using redux, all tabs update, except for views living inside a <NavigatorIOS> inside a tab bar item.

Comment: @Ed. I connected the component, which is mounted by `NavigatorIOS` with redux. Just bypass the "update-issue" of `NavigatorIOS`.
`TabBarIOS` > `NavigatorIOS` > `connect(Component)`

Comment: @purii, Can you please explain how and where you connect(Component)?  I do not know how you do this.  I have a question here on the subject, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817128/redux-navigatorios-does-not-update-state-in-child-views-in-react-native

Comment: I think I am starting to figure it out.  I made some wrapper components that connect the mapStateToProps to mapDispatchToProps and pass {...this.props} to the component that lives inside NavigatorIOS. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Great. I just wrote an answer to your posted question :)

Comment: I made wrapper components that connect the mapStateToProps to mapDispatchToProps, then in the render function, return <MasterView {...this.props} /> to the component that lives inside NavigatorIOS. I made another wrapper component for  <DetailView {...this.props} />.  I may only need to connect <DetailView> by the time I get it working.  Thank you for your suggestion @purii

Comment: Check your question and write your comment there, @Ed. :)